# java.lang.OutOfMmeoryError with 7 inch deviced?

Tags: java, android

The app runs fine on 5 inch and 10 inch devices, i have tested it on real 5 inch and 10 inch devices, however i don't have a real 7 inch devices ! when i try to run the app on a virtual 7 inch device the app crashes and the error is  "java.lang.OutOfMmeoryError", any help please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the Virtual Device you have used has less memory declared than your Application Size. Please check the RAM and memory size of the virtual device using Android Virtual Device Manager and if it has less memory, increase the memory size.

Comment: Yes, that worked my VM heap was to low on the virtual device, thank you!